# Spark Streaming + Kafka integration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I try to integrate spark and kafka **in Jupyter notebook** by using **pyspark**. Here is my work environment.

Spark version: Spark 2.2.1
Kafka version: Kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2
Spark streaming kafka jar: spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.1.jar

I added a Spark streaming kafka assembly jar file to spark-defaults.conf file.

When i start streamingContext for pyspark streaming, this error appears as **can't read kafka version from MANIFEST.MF.**

[image]

Here is my code.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import sys
import os

from kafka import KafkaProducer

#Receive data handler
def handler(message):
    records = message.collect()
    for record in records:
        print(record)
        #producer.send('receive', str(res))
        #producer.flush()

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='slave02:9092')
sc = SparkContext(appName="SparkwithKafka")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

#Create Kafka streaming with argv
zkQuorum = 'slave02:2181'
topic = 'send'
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic:1})
kvs.foreachRDD(handler)

ssc.start()
```

Comment: What is your command for submitting the code? Or how are you loading the JARs into jupyter?

Comment: EDIT : My bad, doesn't looks like an api for python
Note : the KafkaUtils.createStream is the old way to read a kafka topic. You should use [Kafka 0.10 api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)

Comment: @cricket_007 ssc.start() is starting code. I tested in Jupyter notebook. I appended jar route into spark-defaults.conf, for example spark.jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.1.jar

Comment: @Bameza But I know the spark is not compatible with version 0.10.0. [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/streaming-kafka-integration.html) So that is why i uses kafka 0.8.0 API. Is it possible can i uses kafka 0.10.0 API in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I figured out this problem. This is a warning and my application won't crash because of it. It works well for me. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Spark definitely is compatible with Kafka 0.10 libraries. I think that "experimental" note on that page is outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my posting in Scala

Spark 2.2.1 with Scala 2.11 and Kafka 0.10 do all work though they are marked as experimental

The proper way to create a stream if using above libraries is to use

```
val kStrream =  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
          ssc, PreferConsistent,
          Subscribe[String, String](Array("weblogs-text"), kafkaParams, fromOffsets))
```

Pay attention to the dependencies for example kafka has jar files that are specific to the version of Kafka Client version and spark version.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```